# Json с заранее неизвестными ключами в виде unicode. Как получить значение text?

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

Есть апи, которое выдает ответ в формате json:

```
response = requests.get(URL)
response.json()

{u'u0446\u0430\u044c': {u'id': 15, u'text': ttttt}}
```

такое происходит, если присутствуют русские буквы. Есть ли способы "использовать" ключи? На месте `u0446\u0430\u044c`, может быть что угодно. этот ключ фигурирует в запросе, но в нормальном виде.

Comment: В чём вопрос-то? Берите да используйте, нормальный ключ.

Comment: да, только там может быть что угодно. как получить значение "text"?

Comment: Все имеющиеся ключи можно получить с помощью метода `.keys()` у словаря, а дальше уже делайте с ними что хотите

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
>>> dct
{'u0446аь': {'id': 15, 'text': 'ttttt'}}
>>> dct[list(dct.keys())[0]]['text']
'ttttt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить значение, соответствующее `"text"` ключу, из первого попавшегося вложенного словаря в заданном словаре `outer_dict`:

```
inner_dict = next(outer_dict.itervalues())
text = inner_dict['text']
```

или для маленьких словарей:

```
inner_dict = outer_dict.values()[0]
```

В Питоне 3:

```
inner_dict = next(iter(outer_dict.values()))
```